# Record Center retention settings for declared records

Tags: 2010, records-management, records-center, retention

I have a site that uses in place record management. We created a custom policy ColumnRetention that creates a record based on a value of a field.

Now I want to archive all records to a seperate record center. I modified the retention settings of the policy as follows

[image: Retention settings]

However my records are not archived to a seperate center.

After some testing I change the retention settings as follows and the records are archived
[image: Multi stage retention]

Is this a bug or as designed? Could some explain the first situation does not work?